# read()/ioctl disturbs GPIO signal?

Tags: c, linux, ioctl, gpio, msp430

I connect a Linux embedded board(based on imx233) and a MSP430 MCU. They are connected via 4 pin SPI, but I use a GPIO for the chip select purpose on the Linux board. What I do is to use poll to detect falling edge of the GPIO(nr 52) then perform SPI reading either `ioctl` or `read()`

```
int main(void)
{

    /********************************LINUX SCHEDULING**********************************/
        sp.sched_priority = sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_FIFO); //scheduling
        sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_FIFO, &sp); //scheduling
    /********************************LINUX SCHEDULING_END******************************/    

    struct pollfd fdset[2]; //declare the poll to be used in interrupt catching
    int nfds = 2;
    int gpio_fd, timeout, rc;
    char *buf[MAX_BUF]; //max=64byte
    int len;

    initialize(); //gpio's are set to SPI_SLAVE
//    spi_init();

    gpio_fd = gpio_fd_open(CHIP_SELECT_PIN); //the CS(SS) pin is opened
    timeout = POLL_TIMEOUT; //timeout 3 sec is set
  //  uint8_t voidFirstDetection = 1;

    while (1) {
        memset((void*)fdset, 0, sizeof(fdset));
        fdset[0].fd = NULL;
        fdset[0].events = POLLIN;
        fdset[1].fd = gpio_fd;
        fdset[1].events = POLLPRI;

        /*** POLL starts to detect chipselects****/
        rc = poll(fdset, nfds, timeout);

        if (rc < 0) {
            printf("\npoll() failed!\n");
            return -1;
        }

        if (rc == 0) {
            printf(".");
        }

        if (fdset[1].revents & POLLPRI ) {  //HERE I need to run SPI_read
                len = read(fdset[1].fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
    /*        if(voidFirstDetection){
              voidFirstDetection = 0;
            }else{*/
                 printf("\npoll() GPIO %d interrupt occurred\n", CHIP_SELECT_PIN);

                 int fd = open(device, O_RDWR);
                 if (fd < 0){
                   //  snprintf(systemlogmsg, sizeof(systemlogmsg), "[1181]: errno:%s Cannot open /dev/spidev ", strerror(errno));
                    // error_logging(systemlogmsg, LOGLEVEL_ERROR);
                     printf("error spi recive\n");
                 }
                 //spi_transfer(fd);
                 do_read(fd);
                 close(fd);
        //    }
        }

    }

    gpio_fd_close(gpio_fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Above code works fine that it generates an interrupt only at the falling edge of the signal. I use the either of the below code when the interrupt is detected to read the `/dev/spidev1-0`

```
static void do_read(int fd)
{
    unsigned char   buf[1], *bp;
    int     status;
    int len = 1;

    /* read at least 2 bytes, no more than 32 */
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof buf);

    status = read(fd, buf, len);
    if (status < 0) {
        perror("read");
        return;
    }
    if (status != len) {
        fprintf(stderr, "short read\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("read(%2d, %2d): %02x %02x,", len, status,
        buf[0], buf[1]);
    status -= 2;
    bp = buf + 2;
    while (status-- > 0)
        printf(" %02x", *bp++);
    printf("\n");
}

static void spi_transfer(int fd)
{
    int ret;
    uint8_t tx[2];
    uint8_t rx[3] = {0 };
    struct spi_ioc_transfer tr = {
        .tx_buf = 0,
        .rx_buf = (unsigned long)rx,
        .len = ARRAY_SIZE(tx),
        .delay_usecs = delay,
        .speed_hz = speed,
        .bits_per_word = bits,
    };


    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &tr);
    if (ret < 1){
        printf("can't send spi message");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (ret = 0; ret < ARRAY_SIZE(tx); ret++) {
        if (!(ret % 6))
            puts("");
        printf("%.2X ", rx[ret]);
    }
    puts("");
}
```

Whenever the either `ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &tr);` line on `spi_transfer()` or  `status = read(fd, buf, len);` on `do_read()` is executed, I see an infinite loop that detects an interrupt on the GPIO52 (chipselect). I try the observe the GPIO via oscilloscope but I could not see any signal change (it might be a spike that my oscilloscope cannot detect), however, when I connect the chipselect to the Vcc, it does not get the infinite loop. As I am on the early stage, I set one of GPIO of the MCU as an output and a constant logic high. I use GPIO52 (Chip select) as an input because my aim is to transfer data from MCU to the linux board.

I guess, the `read()` and `ioctl` somehow effects the GPIO to sink more current than the GPIO can provide. If it is the problem, what can I do that ioctl or read() would not disturb GPIO. Or do you think something else could be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was lucky that I found the problem quick. I tied the grounds of both boards and now it works fine. I will keep the post as someone else might have the same problem. But I am still curious how ioctl or read disturbs the GPIO signal level